# Having the highest value in a interval appear less often

Tags: probability

I have an array of size 5. And initially in each index, they are initialized with the value 1.

so it looks like this : 1 1 1 1 1

Every iteration, I get a decimal value between 0.0 and 1.0. At the first iteration, each index has a 20% chance of being picked. So each interval is broken up like: 0.0 ~ 0.2 | 0.2 ~ 0.4 | 0.4 ~ 0.6 | 0.6 ~ 0.8 | 0.8 ~ 1.0

Lets say, index 2 has got chosen. The array will look like

1 1 2 1 1

I now want to divide the interval so that the index with the value 2 has a lower interval compared to the index with 1's, so that there is a more higher chance for the indices with the value 1's to get chosen. I'm not quite sure how to approach this. Does anyone have an idea or can point me to some resources?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much more likely you want the selection of the "1" entries to be. I'll assume you have a simple model where, if, for example, the array is $[1,2,6,3,8]$ then:

- Entry 0 is twice as likely as Entry 1
- Entry 0 is eight times as likely as Entry 4
- Entry 1 is three times as likely as Entry 2
- etc.

Let the array be $[a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4]$ and let $S= \dfrac{1}{a_0} + \dfrac{1}{a_1} + \dfrac{1}{a_2} + \dfrac{1}{a_3} + \dfrac{1}{a_4}$.

Then we want the probabilities of selection of the next entry to be, for $i=0,1,2,3,4$,

$$P(\text{Select $i^{th}$ entry}) = \dfrac{1}{S}\dfrac{1}{a_i}.$$

And the sub-intervals of $[0,1]$ will be

\begin{eqnarray*}
0 &-& \dfrac{1}{S}\dfrac{1}{a_0} \\
\dfrac{1}{S}\dfrac{1}{a_0} &-& \dfrac{1}{S} \left(\dfrac{1}{a_0} + \dfrac{1}{a_1}\right) \\
\dfrac{1}{S} \left(\dfrac{1}{a_0} + \dfrac{1}{a_1}\right) &-& \dfrac{1}{S} \left(\dfrac{1}{a_0} + \dfrac{1}{a_1} + \dfrac{1}{a_2}\right) \\
\dfrac{1}{S} \left(\dfrac{1}{a_0} + \dfrac{1}{a_1} + \dfrac{1}{a_2}\right) &-& \dfrac{1}{S} \left(\dfrac{1}{a_0} + \dfrac{1}{a_1} + \dfrac{1}{a_2} + \dfrac{1}{a_3}\right) \\
\dfrac{1}{S} \left(\dfrac{1}{a_0} + \dfrac{1}{a_1} + \dfrac{1}{a_2} + \dfrac{1}{a_3}\right) &-& 1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

**Example:**

Array: $[a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4] = [1,2,6,3,8]$.

Then, $S = \dfrac{1}{a_0} + \dfrac{1}{a_1} + \dfrac{1}{a_2} + \dfrac{1}{a_3} + \dfrac{1}{a_4} = \dfrac{51}{24}.$

Probabilities:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(\text{Select Entry $0$}) &=& \dfrac{1}{S}\dfrac{1}{a_0} = \dfrac{24}{51}\dfrac{1}{1} = \dfrac{24}{51} \\
P(\text{Select Entry $1$}) &=& \dfrac{1}{S}\dfrac{1}{a_1} = \dfrac{24}{51}\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{12}{51} \\
P(\text{Select Entry $2$}) &=& \dfrac{1}{S}\dfrac{1}{a_2} = \dfrac{24}{51}\dfrac{1}{6} = \dfrac{4}{51} \\
P(\text{Select Entry $3$}) &=& \dfrac{1}{S}\dfrac{1}{a_3} = \dfrac{24}{51}\dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{8}{51} \\
P(\text{Select Entry $4$}) &=& \dfrac{1}{S}\dfrac{1}{a_4} = \dfrac{24}{51}\dfrac{1}{8} = \dfrac{3}{51}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Sub-intervals:

\begin{eqnarray*}
0 &-& \dfrac{24}{51} \\
\dfrac{24}{51} &-& \dfrac{36}{51} \\
\dfrac{36}{51} &-& \dfrac{40}{51} \\
\dfrac{40}{51} &-& \dfrac{48}{51} \\
\dfrac{48}{51} &-& 1.
\end{eqnarray*}